# MYSQL LIMIT not working as expected - Java

Tags: java, mysql, limit

I have this weird problem in java when trying to fetch records from MYSql database by using the limit function in the query. Not sure what went wrong or did wrong, this query is giving me a hard time.

Issue - When I run this query through my java program it returns all the records and not limiting the records to 10 as given in the limit.

The same query when ran in MYSql command line, it execute very well and fetches me only 10 recrods.

Below is the java code and query. Any help or support is appreciated.!

Java code -

```
public UserVO getApplUserDetailsList(UserVO userVO) throws CAPDAOException {

     List<UserVO> returnList = null;
     String methodName = "getApplUserDetails()";
     Session session = null;
     String queryString = null;
     Transaction transaction = null;
     PreparedStatement ps = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;

     if(userVO == null)
     {
         logger.writeToTivoliAlertLog(className, CAPConstants.ERROR, methodName, null, "userVO returned null. Busines validation error.!", null);
         throw new CAPDAOException("userVO returned null. Busines validation error.!",CAPException.BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR_SECURITY);
     }

      try {

         returnList = new ArrayList<UserVO>();

         System.out.println("");
         String appusr = userVO.getAppUsrNm(); 
         session = getSession();
         transaction = session.beginTransaction();

          if(userVO.getAppUsrRoleCd()!=null && !userVO.getAppUsrRoleCd().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(CAPConstants.DEFAULT_DROPDOWN_VALUE)){

              queryString = "SELECT " +
                                "APPL_USR_ID,APPL_USR_NM,APPL_USR_FRST_NM, " +
                                "APPL_USR_LST_NM,ACCESS_ROLE_CD " +
                                "FROM APPL_USR " +
                                "WHERE " +
                                "APPL_USR_NM LIKE ?"+
                                " AND APPL_USR_FRST_NM LIKE ?"+
                                " AND APPL_USR_LST_NM LIKE ?"+
                                " AND ACCESS_ROLE_CD = ?"+
                                " AND APPL_USR_ID != ?";

                ps = session.connection().prepareStatement(queryString);

                ps.setString(1,userVO.getAppUsrNm()+CAPConstants.PERCENTILE_SYMBOL);
                ps.setString(2,userVO.getAppUsrFirstNm()+CAPConstants.PERCENTILE_SYMBOL);
                ps.setString(3,userVO.getAppUsrLastNm()+CAPConstants.PERCENTILE_SYMBOL);
                ps.setString(4,userVO.getAppUsrRoleCd());
                ps.setInt(5, 1);

          }
          else
          {
              queryString = "SELECT " +
                        "APPL_USR_ID,APPL_USR_NM,APPL_USR_FRST_NM, " +
                        "APPL_USR_LST_NM,ACCESS_ROLE_CD " +
                        "FROM APPL_USR " +
                        "WHERE " +
                        "APPL_USR_NM LIKE ?"+
                        " AND APPL_USR_FRST_NM LIKE ?"+
                        " AND APPL_USR_LST_NM LIKE ?"+
                        " AND APPL_USR_ID != ?";

        ps = session.connection().prepareStatement(queryString);

        ps.setString(1,userVO.getAppUsrNm()+CAPConstants.PERCENTILE_SYMBOL);
        ps.setString(2,userVO.getAppUsrFirstNm()+CAPConstants.PERCENTILE_SYMBOL);
        ps.setString(3,userVO.getAppUsrLastNm()+CAPConstants.PERCENTILE_SYMBOL);
        ps.setInt(4, 1);

          }

          if(userVO.getQueryAction()!=null && userVO.getQueryAction().equals(CAPConstants.GET_DATA))
          queryString += " ORDER BY APPL_USR_ID LIMIT " + userVO.getPAGE_MIN_LIMIT() + ", " + userVO.getPAGE_MAX_LIMIT();
          else
              queryString += " ORDER BY APPL_USR_ID";

         rs = ps.executeQuery();

         if(userVO.getQueryAction()!=null &&         userVO.getQueryAction().equals(CAPConstants.GET_DATA))
         {

            int tempCOunt = 0;

             while(rs!=null && rs.next())
             {
                 tempCOunt ++;

                 UserVO returnVO = new UserVO();

                 returnVO.setAppUsrId(rs.getInt("APPL_USR_ID"));
                 returnVO.setAppUsrNm(rs.getString("APPL_USR_NM"));
                 returnVO.setAppUsrFirstNm(rs.getString("APPL_USR_FRST_NM"));
                 returnVO.setAppUsrLastNm(rs.getString("APPL_USR_LST_NM"));

                 if (rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD")!=null && rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD").trim().equalsIgnoreCase(CAPConstants.ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE_CD))
                         returnVO.setApplicationLevelRole("Administrator");
                 else if (rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD")!=null && rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD").trim().equalsIgnoreCase(CAPConstants.MAINTAINER_ROLE_CD))
                     returnVO.setApplicationLevelRole("Maintainer");
                 else if (rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD")!=null && rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD").trim().equalsIgnoreCase(CAPConstants.VIEWER_ROLE_CD))
                     returnVO.setApplicationLevelRole("Viewer");
                 else
                     returnVO.setApplicationLevelRole("None");

                 returnList.add(returnVO);

             }

             System.out.println("Count >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+tempCOunt);

             userVO.setReturnListFromDB(returnList);
         }
         else
         {

            int rowcount = 0;
            if (rs.last()) {
              rowcount = rs.getRow();
              rs.beforeFirst(); // not rs.first() because the rs.next() below will move on, missing the first element
            }

            userVO.setTotalRecordCount(rowcount);

            System.out.println("Total count of the records to be used for pagination >> "+rowcount);

            rowcount = 0;

             while(rs!=null && rs.next())
             {
                 rowcount ++;
                 UserVO returnVO = new UserVO();

                 returnVO.setAppUsrId(rs.getInt("APPL_USR_ID"));
                 returnVO.setAppUsrNm(rs.getString("APPL_USR_NM"));
                 returnVO.setAppUsrFirstNm(rs.getString("APPL_USR_FRST_NM"));
                 returnVO.setAppUsrLastNm(rs.getString("APPL_USR_LST_NM"));

                 if (rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD")!=null && rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD").trim().equalsIgnoreCase(CAPConstants.ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE_CD))
                         returnVO.setApplicationLevelRole("Administrator");
                 else if (rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD")!=null && rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD").trim().equalsIgnoreCase(CAPConstants.MAINTAINER_ROLE_CD))
                     returnVO.setApplicationLevelRole("Maintainer");
                 else if (rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD")!=null && rs.getString("ACCESS_ROLE_CD").trim().equalsIgnoreCase(CAPConstants.VIEWER_ROLE_CD))
                     returnVO.setApplicationLevelRole("Viewer");
                 else
                     returnVO.setApplicationLevelRole("None");

                 returnList.add(returnVO);

                 System.out.println("Row count >>"+rowcount);

                 if(rowcount == CAPConstants.PAGINATION_MAX_VALUE)
                     break;

             }

             rowcount = 0;

             userVO.setReturnListFromDB(returnList);

         }



         System.out.println("returnList >>"+returnList);


         return userVO;

       } catch (Throwable e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
            logger.writeToTivoliAlertLog(className, CAPConstants.ERROR, methodName, userVO.getAppUsrNm(), "Error occured while trying to fetch application user details. Printing stack trace to the log for analysis..", e);
            throw new CAPDAOException("Error occured while trying to fetch application user details.",CAPException.SPEXECUTION_ERROR_CODE);

       }
      finally{

          closeTransactionAndSession(session,transaction);

      }

}
```

MYSQL Query -

```
SELECT APPL_USR_ID,APPL_USR_NM,APPL_USR_FRST_NM, APPL_USR_LST_NM,ACCESS_ROLE_CD 
FROM APPL_USR WHERE APPL_USR_NM LIKE '%' 
       AND APPL_USR_FRST_NM LIKE '%' 
       AND APPL_USR_LST_NM LIKE '%' 
       AND APPL_USR_ID != 1 
ORDER BY APPL_USR_ID 
LIMIT 10, 10
```

Comment: Just to add more.. below are my version details - MySQL - 5.5.23 Jre - 1.6

Comment: Did you check the queryString just before `rs = ps.executeQuery();`? Does it include the `LIMIT`?

Comment: Have you checked that the condition to add the limit is actually met and that the you are not going into the branch that does not add the limit? Inspect your query string just before the execution to ensure it contains the limit.

Comment: @Sirish what's the result of the current query?

Comment: Hi Guys, you are right.! I just fixed it and writing up this comment. I have update the query right after its execution instead of setting the limit values before the ps = session.connection().prepareStatement(queryString); statement. I have updated the code and its working fine.! THank you guys for jumping in so quick.! Appreciate your help.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the querystring after you have prepared the statement with the string.

Comment: Hi Guys, you are right.! I just fixed it and writing up this comment. I have update the query right after its execution instead of setting the limit values before the ps = session.connection().prepareStatement(queryString); statement. I have updated the code and its working fine.! THank you guys for jumping in so quick.! Appreciate your help.!

Answer (score 4):

you add your LIMIT after

```
ps = session.connection().prepareStatement(queryString);
```

so when calling

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

the LIMIT is not in there.

So, call *prepareStatement* when the *queryString* construction is finished.

Comment: I think that's it. Check `queryString` just before `rs = ps.executeQuery();` to be sure.

Comment: Thank you.! You are right.! Did the change and its working good.